# labelling an equation containing side by side matrices

Tags: labels

I have an equation whose code is as below:

```
\[V=
\begin{bmatrix} \

x'\\
y'\\
\end{bmatrix}%\hspace*{20pt} % to increase the horizontal space

\begin{bmatrix}
   x \cdot \cos(a) - y \cdot \sin(a)\\
y \cdot \cos(a) + x \cdot \sin(a)\\

\end{bmatrix}
\label{Equ.3.6}
\]
```

I want to label this equation as (3.6), but I am not able to figure out where to add  the \label{Equ. 3.6} command. I tried adding it at various positions in the above code but could never get the label of the equation displayed.

Comment: If you want to manually tag the equation, use `\tag` and a numbering environment.

Comment: i corrected the code highlighting, but i'm not sure whether you really mean to have those blank lines in the equation; they really shouldn't be there -- they will result in error messages.  that said, the `\label` is in the right place for a one-line displayed equation, but you need to use `\begin{equation} ... `\end{equation}` instead of `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah... I got it now... Thanks for editing the code  and your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\label` doesn't produce tags; it just sets the string for cross-referencing the object; in your code, however, `\label` is doing nothing since there's no numbering for eventual cross references.

To have your equation numbered, since it fits in one logical line, you can use the `equation` environment, which automatically produces numbering (which can be further customized, if required); the standard `\label`, `\eqref` (requires `amsmath`) mechanism will then allow cross-referencing the expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
As we see in Equation~\eqref{equ:matrix},
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:matrix}
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \cdot \cos(a) - y \cdot \sin(a)\\
y \cdot \cos(a) + x \cdot \sin(a)\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you want, for some reason, to manually provide a tag for the expression, you can use the `equation` environment and `\tag`; once again, the standard `\label`, `\eqref` mechanism will then allow cross-referencing the expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
As we see in Equation~\eqref{equ:matrix},
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:matrix}
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \cdot \cos(a) - y \cdot \sin(a)\\
y \cdot \cos(a) + x \cdot \sin(a)\\
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{3.6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but you don't need to use `\tag` -- the `equation` environment numbers things automatically *unless* overridden by `\tag`.

Comment: @barbara beeton which is why I said "manually provide a tag". My interpretation of the question is that a manual tag was required. Do you think I should add some to my answer?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added some additional comment to my answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @ShraySharan Based on a comment by barbara beeton, I updated my answer. I wan't sure of you wanted a manual tag or just an automatic numbering, so I added both options.